# Anotherway for getting the latitude and longitude

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, latitude-longitude

I am doing one application.In that i want to find out the latitude and longitude values of present location in separate thread.But in separate thread CLLocationManager delegate methods are not fired.So please tell me is there any other way to get that information

Comment: Why do you even want it to run on the separate thread in the first place?

Comment: I don't want to distrub the main thread.SO i want to do in separate thhread.

Comment: And i want to update my location details when the app is in background also.For tthis just i mention the UIBackgroundModes in INfo.plist.Is it sufficient or may i need to do anything.IF i mension like that then automatically didupdatelocation delegate method will fore or i need to do anything for that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question.
You don't need that!

Just use the standard way of Cllocatiomanager delegate (didUpdatFromLocation...).
This is all you need, that works in background, too. Getting that info is fast, that will in now way affect the performance of the main thread.

If you would have time consuming calulcations **after** you have got the lat/lon location, then you can send the coordinates to another thread which performs that calculations. But this then is in your responsibility, and does not interfere with apples framework.

And: there is no other way to get the current lat/lon, only didUpdateFromLocation...